# Boostrap4 helper classes pull-xs-left

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

This in theory should work no? I am trying to float this box to the right ... on a row with 3 columns.... what am i doing wrong here?

Here is a pen: https://codepen.io/lucky500/pen/JbMMby

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <div class="column col-xs-4 pull-xs-left">
    <div class="card card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
      <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of bootstrap 4 you're using in the codepen doesn't contain pull-{breakpoint}-{left/right}. BS4's classes have been rapidly changing as of lately so you may have trouble using classes in their documentation. For instance, pull- have changed to float- just recently.

You can still use pull-left and pull-right in your example's version of BS4.

Answer (score -2):

The Bootstrap4 Extension contains the `col-pull-*` and `col-push-*` classes.

Solution:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="column col-xs-4 col-push-3">
                <div class="card card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
                    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://bootstrap-extension.com/

Comment: Please include the relevant details here.